# foreach empty element in array set element in other array

Tags: php, arrays, post, foreach

i am fetching some $_POST vars and put them in an array likes this:

```
foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $key) {
    $clean[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$key]);
}
```

the result is an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [pers_anrede] => Frau
    [pers_titel] => Dr.
    [pers_vorname] => BLa
    [pers_nachname] => blablabla
    [pers_vorwahl] => 0123
    [pers_telefon] => 3456789
    [job_bundesland] => Berlin
    [job_plz] => 
    [job_ort] => 
    [job_str] => 
)
```

now, what i want to do is some form of simple validation. if an element of the array above has any value, its error is set to false. if a value for the element is missing, its error is set to true. i would like to get an array like this (keeping the example data from above, only the last three elements would produce an error:

```
Array
(
    [pers_anrede] => false
    [pers_titel] => false
    [pers_vorname] => false
    [pers_nachname] => false
    [pers_vorwahl] => false
    [pers_telefon] => false
    [job_bundesland] => false
    [job_plz] => true
    [job_ort] => true
    [job_str] => true
)
```

with this array i want to be able to do things like this etc:

```
if $error['pers_anrede'] == true {
      $error_message = 'please correct blabla';
}
```

thanks for helping out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will loop through your clean array's keys and load an error array that stores true if they are empty:

```
foreach ( array_keys( $clean ) as $key )
    $error[$key] = empty( $clean[$key] );
```

or if you don't want to use array keys:

```
foreach ( $clean as $key => $value )
    $error[$key] = empty( $value );
```

Comment: -1 for useless use of array_keys. Checkout foreach syntax http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($clean as $k => $value) {
    $errors[$k] = empty($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a couple of array functions to get all keys of the items that have an error in a new array:

```
$data = array(
    'pers_anrede' => 'Frau',
    'pers_titel' => null,
    'pers_vorname' => 'BLa',
);

$filtered = array_filter($data);
$error = array_combine(array_keys(array_diff_key($data, $filtered)),
                       array(true));
```

And then:

```
if(isset($error['pers_titel'])) {
    // blah
}
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/Yx6mr)**.

Answer (score 0):

That should be easy with one more foreach loop.

Assuming you are storing the array in $array.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
 if($value == NULL){
  $array[$key] = true;
 }else{
  $array[$key] = false;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do your validation, you will still need to foreach on `$error` array.

So it is simpler to do your validation like this:

```
foreach ($clean as $key=>$value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
        $error_message .= "$key field is required<br/>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use

```
foreach ($clean as $k => $value) {
    $validate[$k] = ($value == "")?true:false;
}
```

empty or default array_filter functions will return false for zero values which you may not want.

> Returns FALSE if var has a non-empty and non-zero value.
>
> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> ```
> "" (an empty string)
> 0 (0 as an integer)
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
> "0" (0 as a string)
> NULL
> FALSE
> array() (an empty array)
> var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
> ```